# Set kubernetes controller-manager "terminated-pod-gc-threshold" flag to a lower value

Tags: kubernetes

I like to change the Kubernetes control manager **--terminated-pod-gc-threshold** value from the default 12500 pods to a lower value (Like 100 or 50) in my kubernetes cluster. Setting this flag to a small one will cause any issues ? Why kubernetes itself set it to a very high value by default. Is that purposefully set ?

Also is there any way we can find/calculate this value required for a cluster ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an appropriate [Issue #78693](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78693) and [PR #79047](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/79047)

[Changed the default terminated-pod-gc-threshold to 500 by hpandeycodeit · Pull Request #79047 · kubernetes/kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/79047/files)

```golang
// run it in your wrapper struct of this type in its \`SetDefaults_\` method.
func RecommendedDefaultPodGCControllerConfiguration(obj *kubectrlmgrconfigv1alpha1.PodGCControllerConfiguration) { 
  if obj.TerminatedPodGCThreshold == 0 { 
    obj.TerminatedPodGCThreshold = 500 
  } 
}
```

PR is [not accepted](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/79047#issuecomment-506541717) yet.

UPD issue is closed and PR not merged too.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Yes I saw the mentioned issues. But still wonder changing this value to a lower one will cause issues?

Comment: You can try code from [PR #79047](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/79047/files) and patch `func RecommendedDefaultPodGCControllerConfiguration`